# Filterable posts using categories

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, ajax, javascript

Hello I am working on a project where I want to display all posts of a custom post type onto a page. I then what to add category filters in the sidebar that could filter the posts on the page using AJAX. So the category filters would be in an list with with checkboxes, that when one is checked it would show all posts of that custom post type that has that category.

I followed a tutorial [here](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html) and it was working to filter via categories, but the way they had it set up was through a select input instead of a checkbox list and when you would filter it would show you the posts on a new page rather than on the same page.

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with this and knew how to push me in the right direction to develop this?

Comment: One of the great features of digital information is how searchable it is.  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213986/ajax-category-filter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ajax category filter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213986/ajax-category-filter)